# Strange reading with Java calendar

Tags: java, groovy, calendar

has anyone experienced such a strange reading from Java Calendar? The following snippet is written in Groovy (in Grails)

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"))    
cal.setTime(this.timeEnd)
def endHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
def endMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
println "cal gettime ${cal.getTime()} -timeend- ${this.timeEnd} end hour!!! $endHour && $endMinute"
```

And it gets me the following result

> cal gettime Thu Jan 01 16:20:00 GMT+08:00 1970 -timeend- 1970-01-01
>   **16:20**:00.0 end hour!!! **15 && 50**

while my date shows 16:20, retrieving the individual field gives me 15:50.
Anyone has any idea?

Thank you,
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ${cal.getTime()} and ${this.timeEnd} are Date values, and are formatted for the default timezone. You need a SimpleDateFormat to display a Date for a specific TimeZone.

Comment: I set the timezone for the calendar object, as I printed it out, it shows the right time (in my timezone), however retrieving individual field (hour and minute) doesn't get me the right time (as in my timezone).. it was shown earlier by 30 minutes.. I'll try using SimpleDateFormat, but it seems to be not so right to use it just to get the hour and minute component... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the time zone of `this.timeEnd` to `"Asia/Singapore"` may have put back your initial *time* by half an hour.

Check your two time zones on [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/)